# iOS code unable to detect URL loaded through UI Webview

Tags: ios

My iOS application is a gigantic web view and we are using a listener script to detect when the user logs out.

```
if([currentURL isEqualToString:@"http://app.edupal.co/logout/index"])
{
    EPAppDelegate *delegate = (EPAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://app.edupal.co/logout/index?deviceId=%@&os=ios", delegate.token];
    NSLog(@"strURL:%@" , strURL);

    NSURL *tulaUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
    NSURLRequest *eduPalReq = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:tulaUrl];
    [self.edupalWebView loadRequest:eduPalReq];

    [timer invalidate];
    timer = nil;
}
```

The listener will detect if the web view ever becomes `http://app.edupal.co/logout/index` and replaces it with `http://app.edupal.co/logout/index?deviceId={device token}&os=ios`

The timer component runs every 0.1 seconds but for some reason is NOT able to detect the URL at all.

Here is the proof from the log.

```
timer2http://app.edupal.co/student/account/?

deviceId=9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a&os=ios
2015-01-08 06:33:21.810 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2 9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a
2015-01-08 06:33:21.914 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2:::::
2015-01-08 06:33:21.915 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2http://app.edupal.co/student/account/?deviceId=9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a&os=ios
2015-01-08 06:33:21.915 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2 9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a
2015-01-08 06:33:21.975 EduPal[1210:371457] LoadingGif Stopped:::
2015-01-08 06:33:22.008 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2:::::
**// user clicks logout button here and /logout/index page is never loaded //**

2015-01-08 06:33:22.009 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2http://app.edupal.co/login/auth
2015-01-08 06:33:22.010 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2 9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a
2015-01-08 06:33:22.109 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2:::::
2015-01-08 06:33:22.110 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2http://app.edupal.co/login/auth
2015-01-08 06:33:22.111 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2 9ce97c872173f8927f878484c911774fec8df83f5bf8e6ec564df7a3deb6785a
2015-01-08 06:33:22.209 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2:::::
2015-01-08 06:33:22.210 EduPal[1210:371457] timer2http://app.edupal.co/login/auth
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use a timer, and do not compare the current URL to anything. This whole approach is wrong. You should not poll like that! Instead, just set a delegate on the web view. The delegate is called whenever the user tries to navigate to a new page. So you will be able to detect navigating to the logout page in that way.

Comment: I will try this and report back the results

Comment: Delegate reference here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006951

Comment: Although you will still need to compare URL to detect user navigating to logout page. Not sure how you can get around that.